# Laravel Eloquent relationship with group by attributes from two models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have two models `InvoiceHeader` and `InvoiceDetail`. **InvoiceHeader** has the following attributes (among others): `id`, `pos_id`, `pos_description` and `date`. **InvoiceDetail** has the following attributes (among others): `id`, `invoice_header_id`, `pct`, `price`. There is a One-to-Many relationship between the two models.

I would like to group by `pos_id` and `date` from `InvoiceHeader` and by `pct` from `InvoiceDetail`. And with that, I would like to get the sum of the price.

From what I found it is not possible to group by both models at once since no actual joins are being made with Eloquent. So I figured that I could group by the `pct` attribute on the `InvoiceDetail`. I do something like this:

```
$invoices = \App\InvoiceHeader::with(['details' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('pct')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(price) AS price')
            ->groupBy(['invoice_header_id', 'pct']);
    }])
    ->whereBetween('date', ['2018-01-01', '2018-07-31'])
    ->select(['pos_id', 'pos_description', 'date'])
    ->get();
```

And it is here that I am stuck. I would need to group by `pos_id`, `pos_description` on `InvoiceHeader` and group by `pct` on `InvoiceDetail`.

From here on I am taking a route, which I think is not the best / easiest one. I have an Eloquent collection of **InvoiceHeader** with a relation to its **InvoiceDetail** collection. I feel like I should work on this, but since I can't figure out how I transform it into a Laravel collection. Since it is the only one that got me a bit closer to what I got I figured I could get on with it. If someone has a better suggestion, however, please do share. Until then, here is what I got.

I make a Laravel collection from the Eloquent collection as such:

```
$collection = collect();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    foreach ($invoice->details as $detail) {
        $collection->push([
            'pos_id' => $invoice->pos_id,
            'pos_description' => $invoice->pos_description,
            'date' => $invoice->date,
            'pct' => $detail->pct,
            'price' => $detail->price,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This brings me to something like

```
$collection = [
    [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-02-28',
        'pct'             => 6,
        'price'           => 68.94
    ], [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-02-28',
        'pct'             => 21,
        'price'           => 99.99
    ], [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-02-28',
        'pct'             => 21,
        'price'           => 82.64
    ], [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-03-31',
        'pct'             => 21,
        'price'           => 431.45
    ]
]
```

This is where I want to get at, or something similar:

```
$newCollection = [
    [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-02-28',
        'details'     => [
            [
               'pct'   => 6,
               'price' => 68.94
            ], [
               'pct'   => 21,
               'price' => 182.63
            ]
        ]
    ], [
        'pos_id'          => 1,
        'pos_description' => 'Somewhere',
        'date'            => '2018-03-31',
        'details'     => [
            [
               'pct'   => 21,
               'price' => 431.45
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried many functions from the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) use `each`, `groupBy`, `map` on the collection. Also got somewhere from [this link](https://trueagency.com.au/insights/code/laravel-collection-simplify-your-data/). But I don't seem to be able to get what I want to accomplish. I feel like I am missing some easy steps which make me do things too difficult.

Disclaimer: Most of the code is loosely based on working code. To simplify things I simplified some things.

Comment: Why would you need a group by instead of just relating details with the primary key of header?  That's the whole point of foreign keys.

Comment: So you have managed to find a solution to your question?

Comment: @Devon, because I need the sum of the price per pos_id, date en pct. I assume you need to declare somewhere you need to group by something to get the sum by that group?

Comment: @andrew, I haven't. the $newCollection is where I want to get at, but I have no idea to get there.

Comment: The sentence > "If someone has a better suggestion, please do share." got me confused.

Comment: However, you seem to have the answer, you just do not build the collection properly, isn't that right?

Comment: @andrew, that, and I haven't the sum per pos_id, date and pct yet. Until I start to create a new Laravel collection it is grouped by invoice_id and pct.

Comment: Instead of using a relation, just use a join. You really aren't seeing a benefit from using relations here anyways since you don't need to get related models.

Answer (score 0):

How about a basic iteration like this:

```
$dirtyColl = [];
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    $dirtyColl[$value['date']]['pos_id'] = $value['pos_id'];
    $dirtyColl[$value['date']]['pos_description'] = $value['pos_description'];
    $dirtyColl[$value['date']]['date'] = $value['date'];
    $dirtyColl[$value['date']]['details'][$value['pct']]['pct'] = $value['pct'];
    $dirtyColl[$value['date']]['details'][$value['pct']]['price'] += $value['price'];
}

print_r(array_values($dirtyColl));
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pos_id] => 1
            [pos_description] => Somewhere
            [date] => 2018-02-28
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [pct] => 6
                            [price] => 68.94
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [pct] => 21
                            [price] => 182.63
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pos_id] => 1
            [pos_description] => Somewhere
            [date] => 2018-03-31
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [pct] => 21
                            [price] => 431.45
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Maybe just use array_values for the 'details' again.